# Select events based on criteria in belongs to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, has-many-through

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :trainings, -> { distinct }, through: :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :training
end

class Training < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :user, -> { distinct },  through: :events
end
```

events table contains:

```
t.date     "date"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "training_id"
```

trainings table contains

```
t.text     "name"
t.integer  "update_frequency"
```

I want to create an array that contains only events that satisfy the following condition:

event.date + training.update_frequency > Date.now

That will create an array that has "overdue" events.

To help explain: For example lets say "Basic Life Support" training has update_frequency = 365 - i.e it should be done yearly. I want to select "overdue " events where the date there were done + a year is greater than Date.now.

Any thoughts would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do this with a database query, because you've got an integer column that needs to be translated into days.  You could do something like this:

```
Event.all.select do |e|
  (e.date + e.training.update_frequency.days) < Date.today
end
```

... but that's a pretty inefficient operation that'll slow way down as your collections grow.

Comment: It is possible to do the above and return an array of all the events that meet that stipulation?